# How to replace a range of numbers from a range of strings with sed

Tags: linux, string, text, sed, range

I'm trying to modify a given text file, wherein I want to change/alter the following strings, eg:

```
lcl|NC_018257.1_cds_XP_003862892.1_5067
lcl|NC_018241.1_cds_XP_003859498.1_1683
lcl|NC_018256.1_cds_XP_003862456.1_4633
lcl|NC_018237.1_cds_XP_003858978.1_1163
lcl|NC_018254.1_cds_XP_003861926.1_4104
```

so that it only contains the `XP_n.1` part of the string.

I have successfully removed the `lcl|NC\_*.1_cds\_` part out of the strings for which
I used the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/lcl|NC\_.\*_cds_//g' cds.fa > cds4.fa
```

The resultant text file contains strings like `XP_003862892.1_5067`.

There are about 8014 strings like this ranging from `XP_*.1_1` to `XP_*.1_8014`. I want to delete the `_1` to `_8014` part of the string and replace it with 1.

I tried using

```
sed 's/1\_./1/g'
```

and it seemed to have worked, however when I scrolled further down the list of strings, the double digit numbers didn't get replaced - only one of the digits was replaced, which immediately followed the '_', resulting in the first digit turning into 1 and the rest retaining their original identity. Same with triple and quadruple digit numbers.
eg:

```
XP_003857837.1_23   --->   XP_003857837.13
XP_003857942.1_228  --->   XP_003857942.128
```

I have absolutely no idea how to remove this, all my attempts have led to failure. Some people have asked me for what my desired output should look like, the ideal output would be: XP_003857837.1, each string should be followed by a .1 instead of .1_SomeNumberRangingFrom1to8014

Comment: sooo you want `s/_[0-9]*$//`?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I have added my desired output. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything in one go with a slightly more complex regex.

```
sed 's/lcl|NC_.*_cds_\(XP_[0-9.]*\)_.*/\1/' cds.fa > cds4.fa
```

The backslashed parentheses create a capturing group, and `\1` in the replacement recalls the first captured group (`\2` for the second, etc, if you have more than one). The regex inside the group looks for `XP_` followed by digits and dots, and the expression after matches the rest of the line from the next uderscore on.

In other words, this basically says "replace the whole line with just the part we care about".

By the by, there is no reason to backslash underscores anywhere, and the `/g` option to the `s` command only makes sense when you want to replace multiple occurrences *on the same input line.*

Comment: XP_003864719'
'XP_003864718'
'XP_003864715'
'XP_003864714'
'XP_003864717'
'XP_003864718.1'
'XP_003864716'
'XP_003861670.1'
'XP_003858414.1'
'XP_003862308.1'
'XP_003864711'
'XP_003858667.1'
'XP_003864710'
'XP_003864713'
'XP_003864712'
'XP_003864729'
'XP_003864726'
'XP_003864455.1'
'XP_003864725'
'XP_003864728'
'XP_003864727'
'XP_003862298.1'
That seemed to have worked although some of the strings are missing the .1 portion. Could i just remove all the .1 off the strings and later add them? Why did some of the strings get clipped like that?

Comment: Without the actual input samples, all I can say is that they probably don't match the expected pattern. Perhaps they lack the underscore after the final number? But then the script would not have replaced the gunk before `XP_` either. Can you share a problematic sample? Probably (accept one of the answers here, or post an answer of your own and accept that, and) ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements spelled out in more detail if you can't figure it out.

Comment: If you want to tack on `.1` at the end if it's missing, just exclude it from the character class, and change the underscore after to `[._]` which matches either dot or underscore, and add a literal `.1` to the end of the replacement string. `'s/lcl|NC_.*_cds_\(XP_[0-9]*\)[._].*/\1.1/'`

Comment: >lcl|NC_018228.1_cds_XP_003857876.1_62 [locus_tag=LDBPK_010630] [db_xref=GOA:E9B7C7,InterPro:IPR019103,InterPro:IPR021109,UniProtKB/TrEMBL:E9B7C7,GeneID:13389784] [protein=DNA-damage inducible protein DDI1-like protein] [protein_id=XP_003857876.1] [location=179084..179815] [gbkey=CDS]  >lcl|NC_018228.1_cds_XP_003857890.1_76 [locus_tag=LDBPK_010770] [db_xref=GOA:E9B7E1,InterPro:IPR000719,InterPro:IPR008271,InterPro:IPR011009,UniProtKB/TrEMBL:E9B7E1,GeneID:13389736] [protein=protein kinase, putative] [protein_id=XP_003857890.1] [location=237051..241286] [gbkey=CDS]
These are sample inputs.

Comment: Sorry, I did not post complete samples, it seemed unnecessary to add the whole samples since  i was only concerned with a tiny portion of the string. Please have a look now.

Comment: I just manually checked all the strings through Grep it seems to be okay and have worked. I don't know why the other software I'm inputting this is detecting otherwise.

Comment: Don't hide details in comments under one of the answers. Again, please accept an answer here and ask a new question.

Comment: `grep`, `sed`, Awk, and Perl all have different regex dialects. You should not generally expect two regex tools to behave precisely identically unless you understand their differences and your regex doesn't use any of those constructs.

Comment: This answers the question you actually asked. It will be useless to future visitors if it actually answers a different question. And obviously you should not edit your question so that existing answers are not correct any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*_\?\(XP_[^.]*\.\)[^_]*_[0-9]\(.*\)/\11\2/'
XP_003862892.1067
XP_003859498.1683
XP_003862456.1633
XP_003858978.1163
XP_003861926.1104
XP_003857837.13
XP_003857942.128
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in this expression, please? Appreciate the response, thank you.

Comment: @itrylinux I have edited code since you provided an output example. It uses back referencing to capture the match within 2 parenthesis groups returned with \1 and \2 respectively. A single integer was excluded from the parenthesis and replaced with a 1 in the replacement.